# Finding MapInfo Pro settings file?

Tags: mapinfo, installation, tab

Where do I find the MapInfo Pro settings file?

I just opened program and it looks like after installation, all my changes are back to default.

I'm using MapInfo Pro 15.0 32-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MapInfo Pro preferences file is called MapInfow.prf.

It can be found in a number of different positions depending on your setup.

Normally, it can be found in this folder: %appdata%\MapInfo\MapInfo.

If you are using the WorkGroup installation, the file can be found in the specific WorkGroup folder.

[image]